# Audio level meter for NAudio recording

Tags: c#, audio, volume

I´m recording audio to a WAV file using NAudio library. I want to be able to update a ProgressBar to the value of audio level/volume as the sample data arrives.

```
public WaveIn Recorder_NAudio;
public WaveFileWriter Writer_NAudio;

public void record()
{
        Recorder_NAudio = new WaveIn();
                Recorder_NAudio.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(sampleRate, 1);
                Writer_NAudio = new WaveFileWriter(File.Open(tempPath, FileMode.Create), Recorder_NAudio.WaveFormat);

                Recorder_NAudio.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(Recorder2_DataAvailable);
                Recorder_NAudio.StartRecording();
}

void Recorder2_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
     if (Writer_NAudio != null) if (Writer_NAudio.CanWrite)
     {
         Writer_NAudio.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

         // I need help to create this function
         ProgressBar1.value = GetVolumeFromBytes(e.buffer);
     }
}
```

Comment: http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/ should show you the ropes.

Answer (score 2):

For a Windows Forms example, have a look at the NAudioDemo source code and in particular the [`AudioPlaybackPanel`](https://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6531ffb004f9#NAudioDemo/AudioPlaybackDemo/AudioPlaybackPanel.cs) class, which uses a `MeteringSampleProvider` and subscribes to its `StreamVolume` event to set the properties on a custom volume meter control (included in NAudio)

For a WPF example, look at [voicerecorder.codeplex.com](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com) which uses a similar technique and the volume metering is described in [this article](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder).

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a control that does everything you want to control can be found [here](http://www.pianetacodice.it/en/2012/10/21/c-vumeter-control/).

For use with NAudio is sufficient to define a device as:

```
Private NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice device;
```

then at any time you know the value of the audio levels of the following values:

Master :

```
device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue;
```

Left :

```
device.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues[0];
```

Right :

```
device.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues[1];
```