# c# Naudio audio level capture and display, only works when sound record property are open

Tags: c#, audio, core-audio, audio-recording, naudio

I have been trying to read the current audio level of a audio input, using that data to update a progess bar and also using the data to make a decision using the NAudio NuGet package in VS2015 (in fact 3 inputs) but can only get the audio level when the sound control panel is open and on the recording tab.

There are a few posts on this [Naudio AudioMeterInformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123754/naudio-audiometerinformation-works-only-if-control-mmsys-cpl-sounds-is-open) and [Audio level meter for NAudio recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556520/audio-level-meter-for-naudio-recording) but I cant seem to get this to work, I am clearly missing something here but just don't understand, can anyone help. if there is a better way of doing this that would be great, i am open to any help

Here is what i am doing, at app startup i check for sound devices and put them in a combo box

```
public void runGUISetup()
    {
        //Check for ini file
        if (File.Exists(iniFile))
        {
            // Set the IP Address of Vmix from INI File
            if (VmixIPAddress.Value != "")
            {
                tbVmixIPAddress.Text = VmixIPAddress.Value;
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
        try
        { 
            // Enumerate soundcards and add to combobox
            MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            var devices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active);
            cBoxSoundCard1.Items.AddRange(devices.ToArray());
            cBoxSoundCard2.Items.AddRange(devices.ToArray());
            cBoxSoundCard3.Items.AddRange(devices.ToArray());

            //Enumerate IP Local Addresses
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());                
            //Populate the drop down list with local IP's
            cbListeningServerIP.Items.AddRange(ipHostInfo.AddressList);
        }
        catch (Exception erSoundcard)
        {
            tbDebug.Text += erSoundcard.Message;                
        }
```

Then I run a timer that collects the current audio level and dumps it into a moving average that then updates a Progress bar. This is the bit that fails and only works when the sound properties is open.

```
        // check audio level every 10ms and store in moving average
    private void tmrSC1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (appActive == true)
        {
            if (cBoxSoundCard1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var device1 = (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice)cBoxSoundCard1.SelectedItem;
                avg1.AddSample((device1.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100));
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if (cBoxSoundCard2.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var device2 = (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice)cBoxSoundCard2.SelectedItem;
                avg2.AddSample((device2.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100));

            }
            else
            {
            }
            if (cBoxSoundCard3.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var device3 = (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice)cBoxSoundCard3.SelectedItem;
                avg3.AddSample((device3.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100));
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

    }
```

**Update:**
Further to Kris's feedback, it does work but only if I hard code the device number,the difference between the two different ways of enumerating sound devices (wave and coreaudioAPI) the device numbering is different and also the decription of each device, so I guess I would need to match the device name of some other fasion?, that would seem prone to failure though. I may be wrong as I am new to this. as ever any help would be greatly received. it also strikes me that maybe I could make the device list using the same method? (coreaudioAPI) and then put the device in to record, I am just not sure how to do that.

[image: UI Display showing selected coreaudioAPI device]

Comment: I am still struggling with this, i just cant seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly the same problem - I got round it by starting to record off that device - even if you do nothing with it. For you, you will need to start recording on 3 devices.

```cs
    // deviceno is an index of the returned devices from enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active);


    void StartAudioDevice(int deviceno)
    {            

        if (deviceno >= 0)
        {
            try
            {
                wavIn = new WaveInEvent();
                wavIn.DeviceNumber = deviceno;
                wavIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);                    
                wavIn.StartRecording();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    void StopAudioDevice()
    {
        try
        {
            wavIn.StopRecording();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i will give this ago at the weekend

Comment: Thanks Kris, the issue is the selected device is a WASAPI device and not a wave device, so I have no way of matching the device up between the two types, the index's don't match, how ever if I hard code the device once I have figured out which device is selected in the UI it does work, so it's a partial solution. any further feed back would be appreciated